# Should I use DynamoDB or stick with MySQL via webservice for my mobile app syncs

Tags: android, synchronization

I have been trying to find an answer to this vital question for a few months but to no avail. So I am posting it here since stackoverflow is the best place for technical questions.

I made an Android app, name of which I'll not mention at this stage. It syncs with a central MySQL database via a webservice on LAMP, which also I created. It all works just great, no problems whatsoever. As the users use the app and perform certain actions, data from their devices gets uploaded to this central server which is running in a data center. As other mobile devices syncs with the database, they get updated with the newer data. At the initial install, app gets a few hundred K of data downloaded via few hundred queries.

Now the problem is that the app has started to get so many downloads that I can foresee I'll not be able to keep up with the sync. For a while I have been optimizing the code both on the Android end and on Web end (with iPhone version still under development), and also using caching techniques, but still, the communication between thousands of mobiles devices and one single database is reaching its limits. Everyday the number of downloads are more than previous day. Now I am extremely worried how to handle this situation.

I have been looking into using Amazon DynamoDB, have also went over its SDK, tutorials, etc. and am ready to spend a few days and switch this whole sync thingy to Amazon. But this will eventually cost me heavily, for which I'll have to charge for the app or use a better advertisement scheme. But that's another issue.

Unfortunately Googling for weeks hasn't helped me on figuring out how to efficiently handle large syncs with thousands of mobile devices, which might get into tens of thousands or probably hundreds of thousands.

In short, what to do to, lets say, deal with 100K devices using my app and in need of keeping in sync with a central database?

Kindly answer if you have faced a similar situation and know how to deal with it in real life.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: question is not really programming or android specific, maybe http://dba.stackexchange.com/ knows more

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'll look there too, was not aware of this resource earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good friend of mine Robert, the server admin at Shopify, guided me in this regard and I thought I should briefly share it here.

Its true that for a large number of users a large number of servers is required. The challenge  here is how to efficiently manage this multiple server scenario.

I also had this question asked in a Google interview which surprisingly I answered correctly, or that's what the interviewer said. I also worked on this type of problem for a company, who was working on a project for Verizon, dealing with hundreds of thousands of customers accessing the server farm via a mobile app.

I noticed same approach for all of the above. This gave me a relief that my own method was also not much different.

So if you are using e.g. Amazon services, use their ELB, i.e. Elastic Load Balancing solution. Use it by cloning the main server, each being turned on or off based on the load on the previous server. You'll also need a DNS server with multiple CNAME records to direct load to multiple IPs. This is a very interesting technology in itself, but Amazon makes it much simpler. DNS in itself is a complicated technology, however a little reading on using CNAME and using it for routing and balancing via Amazon will help very quickly.

Now there is obviously also a database involved in any given architect. In my case it has always been MySQL. I tried and gave up on Amazon's DynamoDB (a NoSQL solution) due to reasons of cost and complexity. Also one of my ex-bosses who was much better than me in understanding differences between SQL and NoSQL explained me once why NoSQL was a poorer choice than SQL. So in case of our problem, we setup one master database, and then its slaves. Each instance of the REST server answering our REST queries interacts only with its own MySQL slave, which in turn is getting updated from the main master database. Its true that this will create a lot of server instances, and will cost a decent amount of money on Amazon, but this is how it is done.

In the Verizon scenario, the solution was from Microsoft and each server was supposed to take load from 25000 users before switching on the next server for another 25000 users. However as soon I hear the word Microsoft, I lose all my confidence on any proposed solution. I could see the issues they had with the whole .NET architecture and licensing. I rather stick with Linux based solutions.

I have seen data centers in Singapore servicing North American market, and speeds are pretty bad. Amazon also offers data centers in different parts of the world. It is really important that your servers are where your audience is. For your blog or similar stuff you can use service from CloudFlare for example, but for your app, better implement your own intelligent architecture with strategically placed servers.

And in the end, I rely heavily on Amazon cloud services and now they have many new solutions to make things even easier for dealing with large number of requests from large number of apps. I don't know all of these solutions but the main architecture remains the same as I described here.

Good luck with your next great app :)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1) If assume your application has lots of reads from the MySQL DB, in that case first option is to add Read replica's(RR), You can add upto 5 Read replica's

Option 2) Have ElastiCache Clusters sit between your webservice and MySQL DB

Option 3) Look at implementing DynamoDB. It is not a replacement for your MySQL and requires good amount of coding effort if your data architecture is tightly dependent on MySQL